# how to make my navbar display blocked lines in bootstrap 4 on mobile view?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to coding. I have below code for my navbar and I am using django. But it does collapse on mobile view but it does not make blocks, that I intend on doing. I have tried classes such as .d-sm-flex as well as col-sm-10 for various parts of the navbar. Where can I place a class .d-sm-flex so that my navbar automatically becomes blocks of letters for smaller screens such as mobiles.

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand .d-sm-block .d-xs-block" href="{% url 'home:index' %}">  <img src="{% static "images/rainbow.jpg" %}" width="100" height="100" alt=""></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:about' %}">About Us <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        {% if user.userprofiles %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="{% url 'userprofile:profileview' user %}">My Account</a>
      </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'postman:inbox' %}">Inbox</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posts:postshome' %}">Micro Posts</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'userprofile:profilesearch' %}">Search</a>
  </li>
   {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'userprofile:newprofile' %}">Create New Profile</a>
   {% endif %}  <!-- login/logout dont need namespace app -->
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        </li>
            {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:about' %}">About Us <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <!-- login/logout dont need namespace app -->
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
        <li>
          {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be needing to use class row first to use columns.. try adding class="row" in parent of col-sm-10

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that didnt really help me :( I do add rows and columns but it makes navbar look distorted

Comment: Sure Jeric, for example if you open propellerads.com (on mobile) and you uncollapse navbar and the menu looks bigger. My problem is that it looks good on desktop but on mobile the it does collapse but when you de-collapse they Nav-Links are very small. Either if I could make them bigger or I could make them into blocks, either is fine as long as they are bigger. When I try, row and col, it actually puts Navbar on desktop out of proportion but doesnt change the size on mobile.Thanks a lot for your help.